# Is there a way to export a series of scenes rendered in Panda3D as individual image files?

Tags: python, neural-network, computer-vision, rendering, panda3d

I am attempting to use a Python script to artificially generate a training set for an image recognition neural net by rendering a 3D model in a variety of scenes using Panda3D.

I have written the code to successfully render the object I'm training with. At this point I'm just looking to loop it with newly generated parameters and save each iteration as an image. Ideally I'd like to be able to do this cheaply and in a way that can be easily fed to OpenCV and the like.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue on my own. I ended up defining the following function:

```
def renderToPNM():
    base.graphicsEngine.renderFrame()

    image = PNMImage()
    dr = base.camNode.getDisplayRegion(0)
    dr.getScreenshot(image)

    return image
```

and then looping over the following with different scenes and a new path every time:

```
renderToPNM().write(Filename('your/path/here.jpg'))
```